# xargs not replacing variable

Tags: bash, macos, xargs

Following script is not replacing % :

```
cmdss='key=%; val=$(redis-cli get ${key}); arrIN0=(${val//requestId/ }); k=${arrIN0[1]}; arrIN1=(${k//,/ }); l=${arrIN1[0]};  m=(${l//-/ }); n=${m[8]}; o=(${n//./ });  if [ ${o[0]} -le 1656656043 ]; then echo ${key}; fi;'

redis-cli --scan --pattern *prod::*::USER::MODEL::OBJECT | xargs -I% echo "${cmdss}"
```

But following script is replacing %.

```
cmdss='key=%; val=$(redis-cli get ${key}); arrIN0=(${val//requestId/ }); k=${arrIN0[1]}; arrIN1=(${k//,/ }); l=${arrIN1[0]};  m=(${l//-/ }); n=${m[8]}; o=(${n//./ });  '

redis-cli --scan --pattern *prod::*::USER::MODEL::OBJECT | xargs -I% echo "${cmdss}"
```

Output of first script is something like:

```
key=%; val=$(redis-cli get ${key}); arrIN0=(${val//requestId/ }); k=${arrIN0[1]}; arrIN1=(${k//,/ }); l=${arrIN1[0]};  m=(${l//-/ }); n=${m[8]}; o=(${n//./ });  if [ ${o[0]} -le 1656656043 ]; then echo ${key}; fi;
```

Output of second script is something like:

```
key=prod::ls::prod::onjoyride.solitaire::c98fddcf-e3aa-448a-8db8-6abf7a5217f3::USER::MODEL::OBJECT; val=$(redis-cli get ${key}); arrIN0=(${val//requestId/ }); k=${arrIN0[1]}; arrIN1=(${k//,/ }); l=${arrIN1[0]};  m=(${l//-/ }); n=${m[8]}; o=(${n//./ });
```

Difference between above two scripts  is only `if [ ${o[0]} -le 1656656043 ]; then echo ${key}; fi;` .

Any idea why it is happening and what i can do about it?
Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: The only difference is the `if` part at the end of `cmdss`. I don't see any way that could affect how `xargs` replaces the `%` character.

Comment: Do you have to put all the commands in a variable like that? It would be much easier to debug if you put it in a script file, then executed that script from `xargs`.

Comment: i can put in script, but issue is that xargs is not replacing/passing %  and i have no idea how to debug that even if i put in script.

Comment: It's replacing `%` in one case but not the other. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I also don't see anything that can explain the results. Can you paste the line calling xargs?